# Python: Issue reading data lines multiple times from a file

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Python2.6 script on a Win32 that will read all the text files stored in a directory and print only the lines containing actual data. A sample file -

```
Set : 1 
Date: 10212009 
12 34 56 
25 67 90
End Set 
+++++++++
Set: 2 
Date: 10222009 
34 56 89 
25 67 89 
End Set
```

In the above example file, I want to print only the lines 3, 4 and 9, 10 (the actual data values). The program does this iteratively on all txt files.
I wrote the script as below and am testing it on a single txt file as I go.
My logic is to read the input files one by one and search for a start string. As soon as the match is found, start searching for end string. when both are found, print the lines from start string to end string.Repeat on the rest of the file before opening another file.
The problem I am having is that it successfully reads the Set 1 of data, but then screws up on subsequent sets in the file. For set 2, it identifies the no. of lines to read, but prints them starting at incorrect line number. 
A little digging leads to following explanations -
1. Using seek and tell to reposition the 2nd iteration of the loop, which did not work since the file is read from buffer and that screws up "tell" value.
2. Opening the file in binary mode helped someone, but it is not working for me.
3. Open the file with 0 buffer mode, but it did not work.

Second problem I am having is when it prints data from Set 1, it inserts a blank line between 2 lines of data values. How can I get rid of it?

Note: Ignore all references to next_run in the code below. I was trying it out for repositioning line read. Subsequent searches for start string should begin from the last position of end string

```
#!C:/Python26 python 

# Import necessary modules 
import os, glob, string, sys, fileinput, linecache 
from goto import goto, label 

# Set working path 
path = 'C:\\System_Data' 


# -------------------- 
# PARSE DATA MODULE 
# -------------------- 

# Define the search strings for data 
start_search = "Set :" 
end_search ="End Set" 
# For Loop to read the input txt files one by one 
for inputfile in glob.glob( os.path.join( path, '*.txt' ) ): 
  inputfile_fileHandle = open ( inputfile, 'rb', 0 ) 
  print( "Current file being read: " +inputfile ) 
  # start_line initializes to first line 
  start_line = 0 
  # After first set of data is extracted, next_run will store the position to read the rest of the file 
  # next_run = 0 
  # start reading the input files, one line by one line 
  for line in inputfile: 
    line = inputfile_fileHandle.readline() 
    start_line += 1 
    # next_run+=1 
    # If a line matched with the start_search string 
    has_match = line.find( start_search ) 
    if has_match >= 0: 
      print ( "Start String found at line number: %d" %( start_line ) ) 
      # Store the location where the search will be restarted 
      # next_run = inputfile_fileHandle.tell() #inputfile_fileHandle.lineno() 
      print ("Current Position: %d" % next_run) 
      end_line = start_line 
      print ( "Start_Line: %d" %start_line ) 
      print ( "End_Line: %d" %end_line ) 
      #print(line) 
      for line in inputfile: 
        line = inputfile_fileHandle.readline() 
        #print (line) 
        end_line += 1 
        has_match = line.find(end_search) 
        if has_match >= 0: 
          print 'End   String found at line number: %d' % (end_line) 
          # total lines to print: 
          k=0 
          # for loop to print all the lines from start string to end string 
          for j in range(0,end_line-start_line-1): 
            print linecache.getline(inputfile, start_line +1+ j ) 
            k+=1 
          print ( "Number of lines Printed: %d " %k ) 
          # Using goto to get out of 2 loops at once 
          goto .re_search_start_string 
    label .re_search_start_string 
    #inputfile_fileHandle.seek(next_run,0) 

  inputfile_fileHandle.close ()
```

Comment: "The "goto" module was an April Fool's joke, published on 1st April 2004. Yes, it works, but it's a joke nevertheless. Please don't use it in real code!"  You should follow this advice.

Comment: There's a missing space before the colon in `Set: 2` in your example file.

Answer (score 2):

```
in_data = False
for line in open( 'data.txt' ):
    if line.startswith( 'Date:' ):
        in_data = True
    elif line.startswith( 'End Set' ):
        in_data = False
    elif in_data:
        print line.rstrip()
```

Just put something like that inside a loop over your files (i.e. os.walk) and you should be good to go

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do something much simpler, like this:

```
import glob, os

start_search = "Set :" 
end_search = "End Set" 
path = '.'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')): 
 inputfile = open(filename, 'rb', 0)
 print("Current file being read: " + filename)
 is_in_set = False
 while True:
  line = inputfile.readline()
  if not line: break
  if line.startswith(start_search):
   is_in_set = True
   inputfile.readline() # Discard the next line.
  elif line.startswith(end_search):
   is_in_set = False
   print('---')
  elif is_in_set:
   print(line.rstrip()) # The rstrip removes the extra blank lines.
```

If you also want the line numbers, wrap the file object so that every time you call readline() it counts the line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'd do is build a generator that uses a simple state machine to extract the data from a sequence:

```
def extract_data(seq):
    state = "Waiting"
    for item in seq:
        if state == "Waiting":
            if item.startswith("Set"):
                state = "SkippingDateLine"
                continue
            if state == "SkippingDateLine":
                state = "EmittingData"
                continue
            if state == "EmittingData":
                if item.startswith("End Set"):
                    state = "Waiting"
                    continue
                yield item.rstrip()
```

Now I can test that generator to see if it really does what I think it's doing:

```
>>> data = """Set : 1 
Date: 10212009 
12 34 56 
25 67 90
End Set 
+++++++++
Set: 2 
Date: 10222009 
34 56 89 
25 67 89 
End Set""".split("\n")

>>> print list(extract_data(data))
['12 34 56', '25 67 90', '34 56 89', '25 67 89']
```

From here it's simple to make a generator that yields the data from a file given its name:

```
def extract_data_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for item in extract_data(f):
            yield item
```

...and to test it:

```
>>> list(extract_data_from_file(r'c:\temp\test\test1.txt'))
['12 34 56', '25 67 90', '34 56 89', '25 67 89']
```

Now build a generator that goes through all the text files in a directory:

```
def extract_data_from_directory(path):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
                for item in extract_data_from_file(fullname):
                yield item
```

...and then, after making a copy of `test1.txt`, test it:

```
>>> list(extract_data_from_directory(r'c:\temp\test'))
['12 34 56', '25 67 90', '34 56 89', '25 67 89', '12 34 56', '25 67 90', '34 56 89', '25 67 89']
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the presentation slides from David M. Beazley at (if you are certain you want to skip the intro, start at page 18):
http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/

That is undisputably (in my opinion :) the very best way to solve what you are trying to achieve.

Basically, the thing you want is **generators**, and os.walk. A snip from Beazleys code:

```
import os
import fnmatch
import re
import gzip, bz2

def gen_find(filepat,top):
    for path, dirlist, filelist in os.walk(top):
        for name in fnmatch.filter(filelist,filepat):
            yield os.path.join(path,name)

def gen_open(filenames):
    for name in filenames:
        if name.endswith(".gz"):
            yield gzip.open(name)
        elif name.endswith(".bz2"):
            yield bz2.BZ2File(name)
        else:
            yield open(name)

def gen_cat(sources):
    for s in sources:
        for item in s:
            yield item

def gen_grep(pat, lines):
    patc = re.compile(pat)
        for line in lines:
            if patc.search(line): yield line

lognames = gen_find("access-log*", "/usr/www")
logfiles = gen_open(lognames)
loglines = gen_cat(logfiles)
patlines = gen_grep(pat, loglines)
# in your example you could set pat as "^[\d ]+$"
```

Comment: Bit of overkill there, Paul.  The question wasn't about searching a boatload of text files, but about finding the pertinent lines within a given file.

Comment: OP writes "that will read all the text files stored in a directory". Doesn't say how many files, nor how many subdirectories... And then again, this is a very good approach to exactly that.

Comment: You're right, it's a great solution for reading through files, I use it myself, but it wasn't really the question that was asked.  No big deal.

Answer (score 1):

You have many issues here.

```
  for line in inputfile: 
    line = inputfile_fileHandle.readline()
```

`inputfile` is the name of your file, so this loop is going to be executed once for each character in the name of the file, definitely not what you want.  You do this twice (nested), so for sure too many lines are being read.

The `goto` module was a joke.  Get rid of it.

When you open the file, don't add 'b' to the mode.  These are text files, open them as text, not binary.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something even easier:

```
grep -E '[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]' *.txt
```

[grep is available on Win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Several errors:

```
for line in inputfile:
```

`inputfile` is your filename. So the `for` loop will iterate over each character of the filename.

You need to do

```
for line in inputfile_fileHandle:
```

Then, `line` already contains your current line. Also, you probably don't need to open the file using `'rb'` since it's a text file.

Then you nest an identical `for` loop inside the first loop (which is currently also completely wrong, iterating over the filename once again).

Not to mention the goto/label nonsense :)

kurosch has written a good version.

Answer (score 0):

```
f=0
for line in open("file"):    
    if "End Set" in line: f=0
    if "Date" in line: f=1
    elif f: print line.strip()
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
12 34 56
25 67 90
34 56 89
25 67 89
```